# How to extract latest rows from Database for specific column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table in the database.

```
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | user_id | timeid              | course_id |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
| 02 |       2 | 2016-01-27 19:24:17 |        14 |
| 03 |       2 | 2016-02-27 19:24:27 |        15 |
| 04 |       2 | 2016-03-27 19:24:37 |        16 |
| 05 |       3 | 2016-01-27 19:24:17 |        19 |
| 06 |       3 | 2016-02-27 19:24:27 |        18 |
| 07 |       3 | 2016-03-27 19:24:37 |        17 |
+----+---------+---------------------+-----------+
```

How can I extract only the latest rows sorted by `timeid` for each user_id?

In other words:

```
| 04 |       2 | 2016-03-27 19:24:37 |        16 |
| 07 |       3 | 2016-03-27 19:24:37 |        17 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way uses `=` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timeid = (select max(t2.timeid) from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.timeid, t1.course_id
FROM mytable as t1
JOIN (
   SELECT user_id, MAX(timeid) AS timeid
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY user_id
) AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.timeid = t2.timeid
```

`t2` is a derived table containing the latest `timeid` value per `user_id`. If you join the original table to this you can get back all field of the record having the latest-per-group value.

Comment: You' ve got an error there, I assume it should be `AND t1.timeid = t2.timeid` instead of `AND t1.timeid = t2.user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql query like

```
SELECT id, user_id, timeid, course_id FROM tablename ORDER BY timeid DESC GROUP BY user_id;
```